# OWL/Protege: Combining Object Properties with Conjunction

Tags: owl, protege

Say I have a class "Adult" and a class "Child" and two object properties "isFatherOf " and "playsMonopolyWith". Suppose I want all fathers who play monopoly with their children. Now I could do a subclass like:

```
Adult
isFatherOf some Child
playsMonopolyWith some Child
```

But this isn't quite right since a father who plays monopoly only with other people's children would be included here. What a really want is:

```
Adult
(isFatherOf and PlaysMonopolyWith) some child
```

The child that the father plays monopoly with must be the same child that he is the father of.

This gives syntax error. So I'm guessing the description logic doesn't allow this sort of construct? Is there a work around?

Comment: conjunction of properties is not part of SROIQ which is the underlying description logic for OWL 2, so that's impossible and as you can see not part of the OWL 2 syntax therefore

Comment: OWL itself doesn't support variables, but it often helps to see if something is possible in OWL when you look at the rule syntax first: `isFatherOf(?x, ?y) ^ playsMonopolyWith(?x, ?y) ^ Child(?y) -> Adult(?x)` - so, the easiest thing is indeed to use a SWRL rule. What you also can do is to check wither the rule is a  *Description Logic rule*, i.e. belongs to a fragment of SWRL rules that can be expressed via OWL axioms. Markus Krötzsch and colleagues did nice research about it.

Comment: @AKSW thank you kindly. If you post as an answer with a like to that work I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Link not like   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to describe business logic, it is often preferable to use inference rules instead of OWL logic.

From your example, if you want a class `NiceFather` for `Father`s who `playsMonopolyWith` their own `Child`, here is what to do.

Go to *"Window" > "Tabs"*, and check *"SWRLTab"*, then go to the newly created *"SWRLTab"*. Click on the "New" button.

[image: SWRL rules view]

Write the rule you described in your question. The syntax is pretty straightforward.

```
isFatherOf(?father, ?child) ^ playsMonopolyWith(?father, ?child) -> NiceFather(?father)
```

Click "Ok" to create the rule, and run the reasoner.

---

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Richard-Degenne/e9f2d0949ad0aa10b5bd60dff19ee283) is a Gist that you can download and open in Protégé. As you can see Albert is a nice father because he plays Monopoly with his son Albert Jr. Bob, on the other hand, is not a nice father because he plays Monopoly with Albert Jr. instead of his own son Bob Jr. :)

[image: albert is a nice father]
[image: bob is not a nice father]

Comment: People often teach/learn OWL without mentioning custom inference rules, even though it's a one of the most important tools of semantic technologies.